Ho to save and edit the form document using power app on sharepoint-integrated-app?
I want to find a way to validate the form before it submit to sharepoint, so that later on sharepoint i can be edit and save it. What is the problem now, on power app the code is not doing that i might miss some steps on using the right approach. What i need the form before submit the button it must first validate, i did this fine on sharepoint when the form is there, just here bit confuse as it send the notification without validating, so can later on come and edit.
// power app
If(IsBlank(Short_Desc_Text.Text) || IsBlank(Responsible_combo.SelectedItems) || IsBlank(Facilities_combo.SelectedItems) || IsBlank(Find_Desc_txt.Text) || IsBlank(Reference_combo.SelectedItems) || IsBlank(Severity_combo.SelectedItems) || IsBlank(Audit_combo.SelectedItems) || IsBlank(Responsible_combo.SelectedItems) || IsBlank('1stManager_combo'.SelectedItems) || IsBlank('2ndManager_combo'.SelectedItems) || IsBlank(Status_combo.SelectedItems), DisplayMode.Edit)
// displayMode
ResetForm('Capturing Form');ResetForm('Correct-Prev-Form');ResetForm('SHEQ Record Details Form'); Notify("Document is submitted and reviewed shortly", NotificationType.Success);
